# Adding column in product deisgner table

Tags: guidewire, gosu

How would you go about adding a column to a Product Designer table. For example if you go into PersonalAutoLine under Policy Lines and click on coverages you will get a table with "Name, Code, Category" etc. Is there a way to add a column on that table? I don't see an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. You have to modify your specific coverage lookup table, and add a new Dimension to the lookuptables.xml under the LookupTable for your entityName.
I added the PolicyTypeGroup and DwellingUsage columns below for DwellingCov.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you